# Count columns based on date range

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm new to VBA. I'm trying to accomplish the below thing in VBA and not sure how to do this.

1. In Column "K" in sheet "Latency" i have dates in the form of "11/10/2016 16:17". (there will be multiple dates in the column)
2. In column "O" I have few vales in a cell "Pass" or Fail"

What I want to do is, when the script is run, it should first throw up a dialogue box asking the user to enter the date range. Once the user gives the date range, it should select that columns and look out for "Pass" in "o" column and count the value and update it in a particular cell.

I have tried the below code, but I'm not sure how to add the count value using the date range criteria:

```
Sub WBR()
Dim s As String
Dim r As Range
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Latency") 'sets the worksheet
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set r = xlSheet.Range("O:O")                       'sets the range to search
s = "Pass"
[AE4] = wf.CountIf(r, s)
s = "Fail"
[AE5] = wf.CountIf(r, s)

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")
    [AE119] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Yes", _
                          .Range("K:K"), "Tablet")
 End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                'no of tickets processed
    [AE119] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Yes", _
                          .Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT", _
                          .Range("K:K"), "Tablet")
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a slight variation on your existing code:

```
Sub WBR()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim MinDate As String
    Dim MaxDate As String
    MinDate = InputBox("Minimum Date")
    MaxDate = InputBox("Maximum Date")
    If Not (IsDate(MinDate) And IsDate(MaxDate)) Then
        MsgBox "You should have specified valid dates!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CDate(MinDate) > CDate(MaxDate) Then
        MsgBox "You should have specified sensible dates!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Latency")
        [AE4] = wf.CountIf(.Range("O:O"), "Pass")
        [AE5] = wf.CountIf(.Range("O:O"), "Fail")

        [AE6] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), ">=" & CLng(CDate(MinDate)), _
                            .Range("K:K"), "<=" & Clng(CDate(MaxDate)), _
                            .Range("O:O"), "Pass")
    End With        
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")
        [AE119] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Yes", _
                              .Range("K:K"), "Tablet")
        'no of tickets processed
        [AE119] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Yes", _
                              .Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT", _
                              .Range("K:K"), "Tablet")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @walterwhile - Also note that your last two `CountIfs` are currently storing their results in the same cell.

Comment: I tired running the above code, but it's showing up syntax error at an unusual place where there was no error before: `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Latency")
        [AE4] = wf.CountIf(.Range("O:O", "Pass")
        [AE5] = wf.CountIf(.Range("O:O", "Fail")
` @YowE3K

Comment: @walterwhile - Sorry - I lost the `)` from the end of `Range("O:O")` - I will edit the answer

Comment: Will test this out. Another question based on the conditions. Lets say a col "X" has A, B, C, D. I want the count if it has only A or only B or both A and B from col X and another condition from a different column. How do i put this condition?

Comment: @walterwhile - do you mean (X has an "A") or (X has a "B") or (X has either "A" or "B", and column Y has "Z")?  That is the same as (X has an "A") or (X has a "B").  But if you mean (X has an "A") or (X has a "B") or (X has both "A" and "B", and column Y has "Z"), then that is zero - a single row in a single column (i.e. a cell) can't contain two values at one time.

Comment: (X has an "A") or (X has a "B") or (X has either "A" or "B", and column Y has "Z") - is my case

Comment: @walterwhile - OK, that is identical to (X has an "A") or (X has a "B"), so just do two `CountIf`s and add them.  `wf.CountIf(.Range("X:X"), "A") + wf.CountIf(.Range("X:X"), "B")`

Comment: Along with this I need to get the count only if Y has "z"

Comment: @walterwhile - so you don't want (X has an "A") or (X has a "B") or (X has either "A" or "B", and column Y has "Z") - you just want (X has either "A" or "B", and column Y has "Z") - that would be `wf.CountIfs(.Range("X:X"), "A", .Range("Y:Y"), "Z") + wf.CountIfs(.Range("X:X"), "B", .Range("Y:Y"), "Z")`

Comment: Got it. Just to be clear for the date search range, it is in the form of mm/dd/year right?

Comment: @walterwhile - `IsDate` checks that the string is a valid date, in **whatever** format Excel can recognise.  So on **my** system, I could enter "30 Dec 2016", or "30 December 2016", or "30/12/2016", or "12/30/2016" (because Excel will fall-back on a mm/dd/yyyy format if it works when a dd/mm/yyyy format doesn't), or "30-12-16", or "12-30-16", or even just "30 Dec" (but that would default to be in 2017 now).  Similarly `CDate` will take any recognised date format and convert it into a `Date` (stored in Excel as a number representing days since 0 Jan 1900).

Comment: The reason why I asked is that, there is a mismatch in count when I use this. The format used in my excel sheet is "mm/dd/year 16:17" (yes, it also has time along with the date). example: "11/10/2016 16:17". Can this be the reason for the mismatch?

Comment: @walterwhile - If you enter a date of 11/10/2016 as your maxdate (with no time, which the code would ignore anyway), then that will be < 11/10/2016 16:17.  You may need to change `.Range("K:K"), "<=" & Clng(CDate(MaxDate))` to `.Range("K:K"), "<=" & (Clng(CDate(MaxDate))+1)` so that a maxdate of, for instance, 31 Dec 2016 is treated as midnight between 31 Dec 2016 and 1 Jan 2017.

Comment: Yes this works!! One last question, how do I add multiple criteria into this? Currently it gets the count of "Pass" in "O", but I need "Fail" and "In Progress"..I tried the below code, but it gave the result as "0":  `[AE2] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), ">=" & CLng(CDate(MinDate)), _
                            .Range("K:K"), "<=" & (CLng(CDate(MaxDate)) + 1), _
                            .Range("O:O"), "Fail", _
                            .Range("O:O"), "Pass", _
                            .Range("O:O"), "In progress")`

Comment: @walterwhile I don't believe you really want to find out how many rows contain (K>=Min AND K<=Max AND O="Fail" AND O="PASS" AND O="In Progress").  You won't find any row where column O contains "Pass" AND "Fail" AND "In Progress" - it can, at max, contain one of those values.

Comment: @walterwhile I believe you really want to find out how many rows contain (K>=Min AND K<=Max AND O="Fail") PLUS how many rows contain (K>=Min AND K<=Max AND O="Pass") PLUS how many rows contain (K>=Min AND K<=Max AND O="In Progress").  So you need three `CountIfs` joined by `+` (plus) signs.  (Or, if "Pass", "Fail" and "In Progress" are the only three possible values that O can take, that simplifies to just wanting to know how many rows contain (K>=Main AND K<=Max).)