# Create Daily Counts based on Date Ranges

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Assume that I have the following dataset

```
Case ID |  Dates Start Date [1]  |   Dates End Date [1]  |
002   | 2020-03-10T00:00:00.000Z  | 2020-03-13T00:00:00.000Z | 
008   | 2020-03-12T00:00:00.000Z  | 2020-03-20T00:00:00.000Z | 
322   | 2020-04-20T00:00:00.000Z  | 2020-04-25T00:00:00.000Z |
```

IMP: Dates are formatted as follows: `2020-04-11T00:00:00.000Z`

I need to create daily count of individuals that were in that location in that particular date range. I can opt to solve this either in PowerBI Desktop or Excel. For example, with this calculation(using the above dataset) I'm expecting to have daily counts like this:

```
10/03/20 - 1
11/03/20 - 1
12/03/20 - 2
13/03/20 - 2
14/03/20 - 1
```

I've tried the following solution but somehow it didn't work in my case:
[Count columns based on date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421598/count-columns-based-on-date-range)

Would appreciate your insight! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with `Power Query`. I'm not familiar with PowerBI but it might be similar.

- Set Type of column 1 to Text, and of the Date columns to Whole Number
- Add a custom column creating a LIST bounded by the Start and End Dates
- Delete the Original Start and End date columns
- Expand the List to new rows
- Change the data type to Date
- Group by Dates with Count Rows as the Aggregation.

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Case ID", type text}, {"Start Date", Int64.Type}, {"End Date", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Dates", each {[Start Date]..[End Date]}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Start Date", "End Date"}),
    #"Expanded Dates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Dates"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Dates",{{"Dates", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {"Dates"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Getting an error when converting the Start Date and End Date into whole number, I've realized that I might have misled you(and will update the original question as a result)

Comment: @stefbmt That's a big difference.  In the first instance, your time stamps are "real" Excel dates; in the second, they are merely strings representing a UTC date/time.  You need to convert them to real times -- and you need to decide if you want to leave them as UTC, or convert to local times.

Comment: Thanks Ron! In fact fixed them to the same format as in the original dataset and got it to work, but had issues with null values. What I did then is rolled back one step in the Steps(within the Query Window) and got it to work. Now, next step is to find a way how to automate this in PowerBI

Comment: @stefbmt Glad you got it to work.  To convert the strings to "real date/times", take a look at the **PQ** `DateTimeZone` functions which can both convert the stamps to "real" times; and also, if you want, convert to local time zone. I think PowerBI has the same functions.